# Streaming Chunked HTTP Entities with vert.x

Tags: java, scala, reactive-programming, vert.x, akka-http

I'm beginning an initial review of [vert.x](http://vertx.io) and comparing it to akka-http.  One area where akka appears to shine is streaming of response bodies.

In akka-http it is possible to create a streaming entity that utilizes back-pressure which allows the client to decide when it is ready to consume data.

As an example, it is possible to create a response with an entity consisting of 1 billion instances of `"42"` values:

```
//Iterator is "lazy", therefore this function returns immediately
val bodyData : () => Iterator[ChunkStreamPart] = () => 
  Iterator 
    .continually("42")
    .take(1000000000)
    .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)

val route = 
  get {

    val entity : HttpEntity = 
      Chunked(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, Source fromIterator bodyData)

    complete(HttpResponse(entity=entity))
  }
```

The above code will not "blow up" the server's memory and will return the response to the client before the billion values have been generated.

The `"42"` values will get created on-the-fly as the client tries to consume the response body.

**Question: is this streaming capability also present in vert.x?**

A cursory review of the [`HttpServerResponse`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerResponse.html) class would indicate that it is not since the  `write` member function can only take in a `String` or a vert.x [`Buffer`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/buffer/Buffer.html).  From my limited understanding it seems that Buffer is not lazy and holds the data in memory which means the 1 billion "42" example would crash a server with just a few concurrent requests.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: First thing that pops up in google: [Vert.x Reactive Streams Integrations](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-reactive-streams/java/).

Comment: @pedromss I'm familiar with the page, the notion of a `Pump` seems to indicate that the `Buffer` would fill up with the billion `"42"` values in memory...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/)? That's the concept of that vert.x reactive streams implements so it should answer your question, no? :) Either that or I'm not understanding the question :(

Comment: @pedromss Yes, I'm quite familiar with reactive streams.  It's possible that `vert.x` implemented reactive streams for connection handling but not entity handling.  This is at the heart of my question: how do I construct a response entity which is a reactive stream???

Comment: May I ask: This looks like a route exposed through HTTP, what happens when you do a GET? (using akka-http). Do you get a bunch for '42's every now and then?

Comment: When you do a get the response comes back immediately.  If the client begins to read the body then 42s get generated as the client reads them, if the client sleeps for 5 minutes before reading the body then the server performs no work during that time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153698/discussion-between-pedromss-and-ramon-j-romero-y-vigil).

Comment: did you get an answer? I am at the same point at the moment :-D

Comment: @auryn31 No, I never got an answer...